# Slick carousel - when reloading a page all images are shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slick.js

I'm trying to use Slick carousel to display product images (main image and thumbnails - https://d26dzxoao6i3hh.cloudfront.net/items/1A1K120k2o460k0P2d2P/Image%202017-10-25%20at%201.54.21%20PM.130n063B272P.png).

But when user is reloading a page - all images are shown like this - https://d26dzxoao6i3hh.cloudfront.net/items/3u1u0I1i21230a1u0w2e/Image%202017-10-25%20at%201.51.01%20PM.1X1M2p1S2D23.png. And then after page is loaded it looks okay.
My js code for carousel:

```
$('.product__image-for').slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  adaptiveHeight: true,
  asNavFor: '.product-thumbnails',
  arrows: true,
  fade: true
});
$('.product-thumbnails').slick({
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  asNavFor: '.product__image-for',
  arrows: false,
  dots: false,
  centerMode: true,
  focusOnSelect: true,
});
```

Should i limit the height of container div? And use overflow hidden? Or maybe some of Slick settings. Did anyone face with this problem?

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

It happens because slick gets initialized (and applies its styles) only after page is loaded. You need to create additional CSS styles to display slick slider into uninitialized state, like:

```
.product__image-for:not(.slick-initialized) .your-slide-selector {
  display none;
}
.product__image-for:not(.slick-initialized) .your-slide-selector:first-child {
  display block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@flying Somehow this didnt work for me. But i've found another solution with visibility and opacity. Thanks everyone for help!

```
.product__image-for,
.product-thumbnails {
   visibility: hidden;
   opacity: 0;  
   transition: opacity 0.1s;
}

.product__image-for.slick-initialized,
.product-thumbnails.slick-initialized {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.product__image-for .product__image-item {
  display: none ;
}

.product__image-for .product__image-item:first-child {
  display: block; 
  visibility: hidden;
} 

.product__image-for.slick-initialized .product__image-item {
  display: block;
  visibility: visible!important;
}
```